# use of where cluase for last_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch row of last inserted id.If the last row value of id is 1234.Then I have to use that value in where clause.I am trying following code.but not working

```
$stmt8->prepare( "SELECT stat_id FROM " ."raw_nw_static_db_icube"."WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID ");
  $stmt8->execute();
$stmt8->bind_result($stat_id);  
$stmt8->fetch();
echo $stat_id;
```

Do anyone have idea to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
$stmt8->prepare( "SELECT stat_id FROM raw_nw_static_db_icube WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID ");
```

For get last id use `order by desc desc`

```
SELECT stat_id FROM raw_nw_static_db_icube order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

**for geting last id which insert on this table**

```
$last_id=$stmt8->insert_id;
```

**getting their value**

```
SELECT stat_id FROM raw_nw_static_db_icube where id=$last_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $stmt8->prepare( "SELECT stat_id FROM " ."raw_nw_static_db_icube"."order by id desc limit 1");
      $stmt8->execute();
    $stmt8->bind_result($stat_id);  
    $stmt8->fetch();
    echo $stat_id;
```

this will give the last inserted result but your id must be auto increment